# Navigation Components: Switch Menu of Navigation Drawer (for logged in users)

Tags: java, android, navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I am using the new Navigation Components library. I have a Navigation Drawer in place that works perfectly fine.

If my user logs in I want to change the menu of the Navigation Drawer. Specifically, I want to change the "Login" item to "Logout" from within a fragment.

All the solutions I  found online didn't use Navigation Components. So therefore, they recommended something like this:

```java
// Get the navigationView and swap the menu
NavigationView navigationView = view.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.getMenu().clear();
navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer_logged_in);
```

However, this doesn't seem to work in my case (I cannot get the navigationView from within a fragment). How does one achieve this with Navigation Components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access **Activity** from **Fragment** through interface:

1. Create and interface say `LoginSuccessListener`
2. Implements this in your `Activity`
3. Inside fragment receive this listener inside `onAttach`
4. Use it as you needed to update `Navigation Menu`

Comment: You just made me realize that I can use geAcitvity().findViewById to get the NavigationView and change that one.